# How to send less no of bits over networks

Tags: java, c, algorithm

I have a requirement to send integers such as `1,30,786,50,34` etc. over the network.  The maximum value of each integer is 1000.  And maximum no of integers sent is 25.

My task is to send them in such a way it should take minimum memory.

I am thinking UTF 8 representation of integer can be sent.

Please make suggestions if there is a better approach.

Comment: Homework question. What have you tried. What does mean 'memory' in your case?

Comment: You don't say anything about what you're using or what you've attempted. For example, you don't say why you want to use strings rather than a few 16-bit numbers.

Comment: Vote to re-open.  The post has been edited with attempt to clarify original intended questions of asker.  Although the original form was difficult to interpret, it did seem to present what I believe to be a generally useful question, i.e. how to minimize packet size when sending byte data.  Please consider re-opening, or make additional suggestions to OP to re-edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using direct integer of utf representation you can directly convert into a byte array. in java you can directly use `byte` array or in c you can use `bool` array. To represent a 1000 you need 2 bytes=2*8=16 bit. (more precisely 10 bits is enough). So as there are at most 25 values your array size could be `byte[] bytes = new byte[50]` in java or in c++ you can use `bool arr[25*10]` or in c `unsigned short arr[25]` to represent those number. Just write methods to encode and decode from those array values.

Answer (score 3):

*[UTF-8](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=MRIAXK-nH6eM0gKk16TwCQ&q=utf-8&oq=UTF-8&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.35i39j0i67j0i131i67j0i67l2j0j0i20i263j0i67j0l2.1297.2929..9169...0.0..0.136.719.0j6......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i131j0i131i20i263.CHTvOKfEWcg)* is a variable width character encoding capable of encoding all 1,112,064 valid code points in Unicode using one to four 8-bit bytes. So because this conflicts with one of your stated goals, *minimum memory*, this is not likely what you want.

Also, keep in mind, the payload (data) part of any network traffic is always going to be accompanied by additional overhead when transmitted.  ( *[As described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)* ).

However, to address what I think you are asking, pick an appropriate `type`, i.e. one that support the size criteria of 0 - 1000, this table, *[Type Data Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)* will help. `unsigned _int8` or `unsigned char` are too small to allow you to send something with value up to `1000`.  `unsigned short` which has a range capability of `0 to 65,535` will work for you.

The max size of (or max bytes) of data can be controlled simply by how you declare your send buffers.  for example:

```
#define MAX_XMIT 25
...
unsigned short sendBuf[MAX_XMIT];//
```

`sizeof(sendBuf)/sizeof(sendBuf[0])` is 2 * 25, or 50 bytes